# How do the characters in Into the Woods actually take responsibility?

Tags: into-the-woods

Towards the end of the movie, I remember each of the characters sing/discuss taking responsibility for their actions (this is in contrast to the song where they place blame), some dialogue from around that time seems to affirm my memory (although I cannot place an exact quote):

> Jack: Maybe I shouldn't have stolen from the Giant...
>
> LRRH: Maybe I shouldn't have strayed from the path...
>
> CINDERELLA: Maybe I shouldn't have attended the Ball...

Which is all well and good, but this is all spurred on by being chased by the Giant's Wife

> whom they killed

When I watched the film, I was quite intrigued by the idea of them facing justice for their actions, instead

> To stop her rampage, the Baker, Jack, Cinderella, and Little Red Riding Hood fake Jack's death to the Giant while she gets hit by the Baker and Jack and falls over, resulting in her death.

- from the [Disney Fandom](https://disney.fandom.com/wiki/The_Giant_(Into_the_Woods)) page.

Which seems like the opposite of taking responsibility for their actions.

How do each of the characters *actually* take responsibility for their actions/crimes?

Comment: I don't think they necessarily take responsibility. They first defeat the giant who is rampaging the kingdom and to save Jack. Then they overcome the character traits that have "failed" them leading to what happens. I think it's more about owning their mistakes and learning from them than anything else.

Comment: See, there's nothing I remember from the films ending that sold me on "owning their mistakes" or " learning from them" from defeating the giant(ess)...

Comment: The Baker was a bit unsure on family/had no son and wanted to do everything on his own, he ends up doing the best for his son and taking a family in. Cinderella wanted out of the house to be a princess, she ends up caring for that family and becoming the mother figure: something in between. Jack was quite carefree and reckless and he's supposed to not be anymore (though that's a bit questionable). I'm not sure what we're meant to make of Red's journey, maybe that she's more willing to listen to others?

Comment: Those looks more like they improved as people, rather than taking responsibility, so it's possible I misremembered the phrasing from the movie!